# Soap POST Request Gives Error for a Specific User, How to Resolve it?

Tags: post, soap, windows-10, gsoap

In windows 10 OS, We have a SOAP client using gsoap library and this client sends SOAP POST requests to a server on the local network.

While working as the administrator, soap requests are succesfull. When I switch the user to a newly created non-admin user, soap calls fail.

I have also checked the accessibility of WSDL of the SOAP service and I can access the page from this new user using an internet browser.

There is no firewall.

Is there a special windows network configuration or permission to resolve this issue?

Thanks.